# SwiftUI: where to initialize frameworks?

Tags: ios, swiftui, appdelegate

With `UIKit` and `UIApplicationDelegate` logic, I used to initialize all the frameworks and stuff in the good old `applicationDidFinishLaunching...` like this:

```
@UIApplicationMain class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       Parse.initialize(with: ParseClientConfiguration() {
           $0.applicationId = PARSE_APP_ID
           // ...
       })
       FirebaseApp.configure()
       // etc...
    }

}
```

I'm now learning how to use `SwiftUI`, but since there is no more `UIApplicationDelegate`, and I've never really used `UISceneDelegate` before, I don't really know where I should do this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63525968/12299030? And by the way about AppDelegate https://stackoverflow.com/a/62538373/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi yes, thank you!